# given a set of $10^n$ numbers how many will have all the digits $0$ through $9$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find out given $n$ how many numbers $k\in [1, 10^n] \cap \mathbb{N}$ will have all the digits $0$ through $9$?

Comment: Possibly all of them, possibly none of them. Are the numbers restricted to some interval?

Comment: Please provide full specifics for your question.  Given $10^n$ of *what kind* of number?  Are they randomly chosen, or can they be anything?  Are you asking how many on average?  How many are guaranteed to have all the digits from $0$ to $9$?  Thanks

Comment: A valid reformulation would be
"Given a set of $10^n$ integers. What is the expected number of integers containing each digit at least once?"

Comment: I meant all numbers 1 to 10^n guaranteed to have all the digits

Comment: @TomSmith So take all the integers $1,2,3,\dots,10^n$ and then you are wondering how many have all the digits $0$ to $9$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how many of the numbers $[0,10^n-1]$ have all the digits, it is easy for $n\lt 10$-none of them.  For $n \ge10$, you need to specify whether you allow leading zeros or not.  If you do, for $n=10$ there are $10!$ numbers that have all the digits because you can arrange the digits in any order.  If not, there are only $9 \cdot 9!$ because the first digit cannot be zero.

It gets harder when $n$ gets larger.  You can either count the ones that don't have all the digits and subtract, but you need to use inclusion-exclusion to account for the ones that are missing more than one digit.  Alternately, for $n=11$ (and assuming we allow leading zeros), you have $10$ ways to pick the duplicated digit, ${11 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the positions to put the duplicates in, and $9!$ ways to order the rest, for $55\cdot 10!$ total numbers that have all the digits.

For $n$ large, almost all of them do.

Answer (score 0):

**First Thoughts**
For $n < 10$, no number has $10$ digits, and so no number has $10$ unique digits. Thus for $n<10$, the answer is $0$.

Now let $n \geq 10, k \in [10^{n-1}, 10^n]$ then $k$ has $n$ digits. Now we want $k$ to have all $10$ digits.
The digits $1, \ldots, 9$ can have any exponent, while $0$ must not be the leading digit and thus has $n-1$ possible locations. When we construct a number of this form with $n = 10$ digits (a valid $k$), we have
$$N_{10} :=\underbrace{n-1}_{\text{digit }0} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^9 \underbrace{n-i}_{\text{digit }i} = 9 \cdot 9!$$
Possibilities. Now for $n > 10$ we have
$$N_{10+k} = \underbrace{\binom{10+k}{10}}_{\text{"target positions"}} \cdot N_{10}$$
This is only an upper bound, because f.ex. $11234567890$ will be counted twice.